# How would I optimize these for loops in Arduino code?

Tags: optimization, arduino

Quickly wrote this code to fade an RGB led through the whole RGB spectrum (I think) and wondered if there is a more efficient way of coding everything in the main loop? It seems overly complicated.

(BTW, I know the speed changes when I change the brightness.)

```cpp
int redPin = 9;
int greenPin = 10;
int bluePin = 11;

int brightness = 255;
int fadeSpeed = 25;

void setup() {
  pinMode(redPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(greenPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(bluePin, OUTPUT);
  
  for (int i=0; i<brightness; i++) {
    analogWrite(redPin, i);
    delay(fadeSpeed);
  }
}

void loop() {
  for (int i=0; i<brightness; i++) {
    analogWrite(greenPin, i);
    delay(fadeSpeed);
  }
  for (int i=0; i<brightness; i++) {
    analogWrite(redPin, brightness - i);
    delay(fadeSpeed);
  }
  for (int i=0; i<brightness; i++) {
    analogWrite(bluePin, i);
    delay(fadeSpeed);
  }
  for (int i=0; i<brightness; i++) {
    analogWrite(greenPin, brightness - i);
    delay(fadeSpeed);
  }
  for (int i=0; i<brightness; i++) {
    analogWrite(redPin, i);
    delay(fadeSpeed);
  }
  for (int i=0; i<brightness; i++) {
    analogWrite(bluePin, brightness - i);
    delay(fadeSpeed);
  }
}
```

Comment: @ocrdu I meant how would I (if possible) write it in a way which is shorter, and doesn't consist of 6 separate for loops. Also you removed the unnecessary blank lines, but added spaces? Is it not less optimized when you add spaces?

Comment: No, just more readable for humans. I mainly edited to get the syntax highlighting in; edits aren't answers here.

Comment: What do you mean by "optimizing"? No need to optimize for processing speed, as your arduino is too fast anyway (see all your delay). No need to optimize for code size, neither.
If you want to optimize for ease of coding, it's too late, as you're done already. :)

Comment: @datafiddler I'm not sure if optimize was a good way to describe what I wanted to know. I was essentially wanting to know if there was a more compact way of writing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's just to minimize duplicate similar code lines, you can define as many functions as you want and define parameters as convenient:

```
void loop() {
   fadeUp(greenPin);
   fadeUp(redPin);
   fadeUp(bluePin);
   fadeDn(greenPin);
   fadeDn(redPin);
   fadeDn(bluePin);
}

void fadeUp(byte pin) {
   fade(pin, 0, brightness, +1);
}
void fadeDn(byte pin) {
   fade(pin, brightness, 0, -1);
}

void fade(byte pin, byte start, byte end, byte delta) {
   for (byte i=start; i!=end; i+=delta) {
       analogWrite(pin, i);
       delay(fadeSpeed);
   }
}
```

BTW: Your solution does not cover "the whole RGB spectrum"

Answer (score 2):

For what you're doing, a bunch of loops is OK. You could maybe built a table of colors and interpolate between them, or combine the common parts into one routine that you call... Define current r,g,b values, and make a routine `setleds(r, g, b)`. Each of your loop will just tweak a single color and call the common routine. It has the nice effect of moving the hardware-specific parts away from the control-specific decisions. (updating pins versus computing rgb values). But maybe that doesn't really matter.

Note that `loop()` won't run very often because of all your delays, and that might affect serial reads if you need them later on.

A different issue is that you're changing RGB, but to do a rainbow we would need HSV - hue saturation value. There's lots of people out there with examples. Here's one: https://eduardofv.com/2011/01/15/arduino-rgb-led-hsv-color-wheel/

I would take his example a step further and get rid of the loop in a loop. Keep track of the current hue, and bump it each time `loop` is called, and update the LEDs. Wrap around when you hit 360. Also, this would make it easier to reverse direction, or randomly sweep around the colors.

HTH! Have fun!

Comment: Thanks a lot, wish I could upvote this, don't have enough score or whatever to do so

Comment: Your'e welcome! No worries.  Anyway @datafiddler's answer is probably better!

Comment: @aMike: Your answer is perhaps not what A_HotMashing was looking for, but widening the underlying question, and thus much *better*. The HSV color scheme is probably more appropriate, and having one loop turnaround for the whole "program" is not useful, except for a demo.